# How does union prevent memory fragmentation?

Tags: c, memory

I am going through this [link](http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/union.aspx) and learning C. Interesting part on the page:

> The real purpose of unions is to prevent memory fragmentation by arranging for a standard size for data in the memory. By having a standard data size we can guarantee that any hole left when dynamically allocated memory is freed will always be reusable by another instance of the same type of union.

I understand this part by the following code:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[100];
    int age;
    int rollno;
  }student;

typedef union{
     student *studentPtr;
     char *text;
  }typeUnion;

int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  typeUnion union1;

  //use union1.studentPtr

  union1.text="Welcome to StackOverflow";
  //use union1.text

  return 0;
}
```

Well, in the above code `union1.text` is reusing the space previously used by `union1.studentPtr`, not completely but still using.

Now, the part I don't understand is, when is the freed up space of `malloc`  can't be used which leads to memory fragmentation?

**edit:** Going through the comments and answers, it is imperative to use [the classic text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), adding this edit to the post presuming it will help beginners like me

Comment: Side note: I strongly disagree with the author about that being "the real purpose of unions" because a) you'd have to use nothing but those unions to even have a chance to prevent fragmentation (and even then, it's in no way guaranteed), and b) you might very well be wasting a whole lot of memory, which is even worse than fragmentation.

Comment: That link looks pretty bad in general. As for your question, I've never seen unions used for that.

Comment: @Siguza: It actually is guaranteed. But - as you wrote - you have to put all other datatypes into that single `union`. That completely is against modern coding principles, namely modularisation.

Comment: Why is the negative vote? any reason would be of help rather than hitting on the arrows just because one can

Comment: That initial statement is pure nonsense! Reason for variant records/unions/howevertheyarecalled is to have a single datatype contain different types of data. It is the non-OOPL way to allow variations for data-elements. In C it also is the only safe way to re-interpret one type as another - something beginners should keep their hands off.

Comment: @Olaf Can't the OS allocate other structures, or align the size of the allocated data? And what about union sizes that do not divide page sizes, won't those create fragmentation either way?

Comment: .@Siguza: The C standard does not even talk about an OS, less does it require one. Re the comment: Sorry, I have missunderstood your comment. Of course that will fragment. Worse: it will eventually fragment memory if you don't always use the full size of the union. If you use a `char [128]` to store a single `char`, you obviously waste 127 bytes. However, there are usages where that waste is more acceptable than the time-complexity of heap-based allocation. (For automatic or static objects fragmentation can always be avoided anyway)

Comment: The site you link to tries to teach an outdated dialect of C, promotes outdated tools, and is generally pretty bad. I would suggest never going there again.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand your final sentence, and that seems like the crux of your question. If you're just asking "how does memory fragmentation occur", that has nothing to do with unions and has probably been answered before on this site.

Comment: You cannot do `union1.text="Welcome to StackOverflow";` It is an *error: incompatible types when assigning to type `char[100]` from type `char *`*

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Corrected

Comment: @Naresh - Your definition of `typeUnion` is arguably poor practice as the union of `student *` and `char[100]` force the compiler to set aside over `100` bytes for either the storage of a *pointer* (`4` or `8` bytes, generally) or `100-bytes` for `text`. You *can* do it, but it just seems -- whacky.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I agree with what you are saying but I am not following the above coding standards, it was just given as an example so that people who are answering understand what I know already and what I am looking for in the answer

Comment: Gotcha, good luck with your coding `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the comments have more expertise regarding `unions` in general.

Regarding your question specifically, this is my understanding:

- `union` sets aside memory for the largest datatype in the union variable. So for example having a `short int` and a `long int` in the union will set aside enough memory for a `long int` [image: 2 bytes set aside for long int]
- Imagine instead of union you declare a `short int` variable.[image: 1 byte for small int]
  But then need to use a `long int`. So you use `free` on the `short int`[image: freeing small int memory]
  Then you use `malloc` to allocate memory for a `long int`. This has to be continguous memory. So now your memory looks like this.
  [image] With a free byte in the middle of an otherwise used block of memory. Sitting there waiting for you to request specifically 1 byte of memory.

**Aside:** If you're learning `c` I recommend [the classic text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). It's dated but I love the simplicity, clarity and text-book style approach.

Comment: Regarding `the classic text` ordered the book without any further delay, appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That page is wrong, most programs simply assume memory usage will be fine and don't pay any attention to it.

In the following diagrams, assume each character represents, say 8 bytes.  Letters represent different allocations, and underscores represent free memory.  The scales involved are ludicrously small, and I'm skipping over details (like allocation metadata used by most malloc implementations), but the principles should be there.

Start with empty memory

```
_____________________________________________________
```

Then a bunch of 32-byte allocations occur as a program runs.

```
AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLL________
```

The memory allocated by the program extends all the way past the last byte of the 'L' allocation, it's using 12*8*4 = 384 bytes.

Now the program frees every other allocation.

```
AAAA____CCCC____EEEE____GGGG____IIII____KKKK__________
```

Now the program is really only using 6*4*8 = 192 bytes, but the operating system has to keep all 352 bytes from the first 'A' to the last 'K' allocated for the program.  Those freed gaps in between all the allocations are an example of memory fragmentation.

Now the program wants to allocate another 32-byte block.  It could happen like this:

```
AAAAMMMMCCCC____EEEE____GGGG____IIII____KKKK_________
```

The new allocation fits in one of the gaps created by the frees, and this is fine since it recycles one of the gaps so we're wasting less space.

Now say the program needs to allocate a 40 byte block.  None of the gaps is big enough, so the allocation has to go at the end and the operating system has to allocate more memory for the program, 352+40=392 bytes.  All of the memory in those gaps is being wasted.  This is the kind of waste due to memory fragmentation the webpage is talking about.

If all of the allocations had been 40 bytes to start with, then gap recycling could be maximized.